# Why null values are not allowed in ArrayDeque?

Tags: java

I know Hashtable doesn't allow null values as it was legacy, which was fixed by HashMap. Null is not allowed in a tree as sorting would be an issue. But why us null not allowed in ArrayDeque?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the Javadoc for `Deque`:

> While `Deque` implementations are not strictly required to
>   prohibit the insertion of null elements, they are strongly encouraged
>   to do so.  Users of any `Deque` implementations that do allow
>   null elements are strongly encouraged *not* to take advantage of
>   the ability to insert nulls.  This is so because `null` is used
>   as a special return value by various methods to indicated that the
>   deque is empty.

The `ArrayDeque` implementation also uses `null` to indicate an empty element (as explained in **sestus**' and **Aman jangra**'s answers), so the reasoning is two-fold: *contract* and *implementation details*.

It's worth noting that it `ArrayDeque` *could* easily support null elements without much additional complexity, so the more compelling reason seems to be the suggestion of the `Deque` interface.

Comment: Is there an alternative to `ArrayDeque`?

Comment: @DavidCallanan alternative in what way? Do you mean is there a `Deque` implementation that does allow nulls? `LinkedList` is one, but as indicated in the documentation, it's better to just avoid nulls.

Comment: An alternative that is implemented similarly to ArrayDeque but allows null. I assume LinkedList is slower and its memory is scattered. But anyway I don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 10):

This may be so because null is used as a special return value by various methods to indicate that the deque is empty.However not all deques prohibit insertion of null values.

Answer (score 8):

Workaround: `ArrayDeque<Optional<T>>` ([java.util.Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html))

```
// Add non-null value
queue.add(Optional.of(value))

// Add nullable value
queue.add(Optional.ofNullable(value))

// Add null
queue.add(Optional.empty())

// Unbox
last = queue.pollLast().orElse(null)
```

Answer (score 2):

The first answer is right on (implementation uses `null` to indicate an empty element). I also wanted to point out that you can always insert an element that *represents* `null` -- something like this:

```
private static final String NULL_INDICATOR = "_NULL_";

private final Deque<String> elementDeque = new ArrayDeque<>();

public final pushElement(String element) {
  if (element == null) {
    element = NULL_INDICATOR;
  }

  elementDeque.push(element);
}

public final peekElement() {
  String element = elementDeque.peek();

  return NULL_INDICATOR.equals(element) ? null : element;
}

public final popElement() {
  elementDeque.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I m not sure if this is indeed the reason behind this, but anyway here is my explanation. It might be the way that elements are removed from `ArrayDeque`:

Suppose that you have an `ArrayDeque`, and you want to remove the element at the right end (the last element). Then, internally, there should be an array, and an index indicator, that points to the last element, that should be decremented. Something like this:

```
// suppose i points to the last element of the array
arr[i] = null; // In order to avoid loitering
i--;           // Point to the "new last element" resize if needed etc
```

That assignment to `null` is necessary in order to avoid [loitering](https://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwict7-TjrPKAhUIQBoKHYCJD2AQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F18109915%2Fjava-loitering-and-garbage-collection&usg=AFQjCNF2bfYfGrk56EyYZzE1nsddEikaqA&sig2=GQ3LPvxUYQOPnbtpn_YD8A&bvm=bv.112064104,d.d2s). Without this, the object `arr[i]` that was removed, would still be referenced (by the internal array of the deque), so it would not be garbage-collected, and that would be a memory issue.

If you allow `null` values on the `Deque`, there would be a confusion on what are real elements and what is just garbage.